# Drop Columns while importing Data in sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I am importing data from oracle to hive . My table doesn't have any integer columns which can be used in my primary keys .So I am not able to use it in my split-by column.

Alternatively I created a row_num column for all rows present in the table . Then this row_num column will be used in split-by column. Finally I want to drop this column from my hive table.

Column list is huge ,I dont want to select all columns using --columns neither I want to create any temporary table for this purpose.

Please let me know whether we can handle this in sqoop arguments.

Comment: Please put down the command you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Can Any little tweek on the --query parameter help you?
Something below.

> sqoop import  --query 'query string'